# image and h1 not responsive as desired using bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I had 2 Div , 1 for image and 1 for heading. I had set different font size as per different media query in CSS file. Although its working while shrinking the width but heading is not breaking in 2 lines and when breaking in 2 lines the header div comes below to 1st div which should be side by side. its not wrking properly. Please help.
Note: The image has 130x130 pixels.

My Codes including CSS:

```
<!-- login.html -->
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta chaviewportrset="utf-8">
  <meta name="" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/BOOTSTRAP/CSS/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- fontawsome icon library -->
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="/BOOTSTRAP/FontAwsome/css/all.css"> -->
  <!--link own style css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/MyCss/MyStyle.css">
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="/MyCss/test.css"> -->
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="BOOTSTRAP/JS/code.jquery.com_jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="BOOTSTRAP/JS/cdn.jsdelivr.net_npm_popper.js@1.14.3_dist_umd_popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="BOOTSTRAP/JS/cdn.jsdelivr.net_npm_bootstrap@4.1.3_dist_js_bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
          @font-face {
            font-family: Britannic Bold;
            src: url(/BOOTSTRAP/fonts/BRITANIC.TTF);
            font-family: Broadway;
            src:url(/BOOTSTRAP/fonts/BROADW.TTF);
            font-weight: bolder;
            font-family: lucida calligraphy;
            src:url(/BOOTSTRAP/fonts/LCALLIG.TTF);
        }
        #logo-img{
            display: block; 
            /* align-items: center; */
            position: inherit;
            /* margin-left: 4%;
            float: left;  */
        }   
        #logo-heading{
            display: inline-block;
            font-family:Britannic Bold;
            width: 100%; 
            font-weight: 800;
            color:transparent;
            background-image: url(/BOOTSTRAP/img/bg-image-multi-color-gradient3.jpeg);
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center;
            background-clip: text;
            -webkit-background-clip: text;
            margin-left: 0%;
        } 
        /* MEDIA QUERY */
        span { font-size: 1.5rem; }

        @media (min-width: 576px) {
            span { font-size:1.25rem ;}
        }
        @media (min-width: 768px) {
            span { font-size: 1.5rem; }
        }
        @media (min-width: 992px) {
            span { font-size: 1.75rem; }
        }
        @media (min-width: 1200px) {
            span { font-size: 2.2rem; }
        }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
<Title>login.html</Title>
<!-- jQry to call heml file -->
<!-- <script src="/JS/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script> -->
<!-- <script src="/JS/include-html.min.js"></script> -->

<!-- header file : "header2.html" -->
<!-- <div include-html="header2.html" id="header2"></div> -->
<!-- xs<576 ! 576<sm<768 ! 768<md<992 ! 992<lg<1200 ! <1200<xl -->

  <!--kept img and text in same div but not resposive  -->
  <!-- ********************************************** -->
  <!-- img & text in one div -->
  <!-- <div class="container p-0">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 p-0" style="border: .01cm red solid; ">
        <img  id="logo-img"     src="/BOOTSTRAP/img/am-logo2-white-bg-117x122.jpg"  height="85vm"  >
        <span id="logo-heading">Arihant Mandal</span>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div> -->

  <!-- img & text in Two div but very alignment of text imporper when xs screen-->
  <!-- *********************************************************************** -->
  <div class="container p-0">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-1 p-0" style="border: .1cm blue solid;">
        <img  class="img-fluid" id="logo-img"     src="/BOOTSTRAP/img/am-logo2-white-bg-117x122.jpg"  height="85vm"  >
      </div>  
      <div class="col-xs-11  p-0" style="border: .01cm red solid; text-align:center;">
        <span id="logo-heading">Arihant Mandal</span>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
```

Comment: Add css that you have for this HTML, you can also use image with full https path and make code snippet that we can run and see the problem

Comment: attached codes with CSS. Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

You have a small mistake in your meta tag.

```
<meta name="" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

Name attribute is empty. Value should be `viewport`.

Here is code snippet with working code

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: Britannic Bold;
  src: url(/BOOTSTRAP/fonts/BRITANIC.TTF);
  font-family: Broadway;
  src: url(/BOOTSTRAP/fonts/BROADW.TTF);
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-family: lucida calligraphy;
  src: url(/BOOTSTRAP/fonts/LCALLIG.TTF);
}
#logo-img {
  display: block;
  /* align-items: center; */
  position: inherit;
  /* margin-left: 4%;
         float: left;  */
}
#logo-heading {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Britannic Bold;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: transparent;
  background-image: url("https://cdn4.buysellads.net/uu/1/134955/1685040267-designdotdev5.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  margin-left: 0%;
}
/* MEDIA QUERY */
span {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  span {
    font-size: 1.25rem;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  span {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  span {
    font-size: 1.75rem;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  span {
    font-size: 2.2rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- login.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>login.html</title>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />

        <!-- Bootstrap CDN -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container p-0">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4 p-0" style="border: 0.1cm blue solid">
                    <img class="img-fluid" id="logo-img" src="https://cdn4.buysellads.net/uu/1/134955/1685040267-designdotdev5.jpg" height="85vm" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8 align-items-center d-flex" style="border: 0.01cm red solid; text-align: center">
                    <span id="logo-heading">Arihant Mandal</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. The code is working but is to possible to put the Text in Center,  and having bit more width. In large screen its working perfect, Please sir.

Comment: For that you need to know a little bit of bootstrap that you are using in this code. I updated my answer. Pay attention on classes for `div` elements inside `row`

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. My hats-off to you for your kind reply. Earlier I was using col-sm-8 and col-sm-4 but this idea put both div below each other but I have intention to bring both div in same row hence I used col-xs-?? by this both div comes to same line in small screen but Text becomes very small of span. I wish to send image of site but I am new to this forum and I could not find way to send image. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: With the help of some video tutorial and some forums like stackoverflow and Foxite , I had made a website with my own codes and launched the same. But now I need to make it more better. www.https://arihantmandal.com